# AND/OR formula structure

Tags: formula

Im trying to build a formula to restrict only 2 users to be able to change a particular pick value, rather than have to build out and maintain another whole profile just for these 2

the outline formula checks whether the set currency is BGP, and if it isnt and the record is not saved by one of the 2 known users, it should throw an error.

```
OR
(  
(TEXT(Currency__c) != 'GBP (£)' && $User.Id != '00512000006evSC'),

(TEXT(Currency__c) != 'GBP (£)' && $User.Id != '0051H000007i6ya')
)
```

For some reason if I use either of the && functions alone it works but as soon as I introduce the OR the error *always triggers* even for the known users

Comment: The identifier of a user is not the same across organizations. This validation rule wont work in production as expected. Maybe you want to use the currency field on the user depending on the use-case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
AND(  
  TEXT(Currency__c) != 'GBP (£)',
  $User.Id != '00512000006evSC',
  $User.Id != '0051H000007i6ya'
)
```

Your rule is failing because if they are 1 of the users **they are not the other user**. Simply changing it to an AND instead of an OR should be enough.

Comment: ah of course - end of the day brain kicking in there. Thanks to all for the kick in the right direction

Comment: @user47837 Don't forget to accept the answer if it's the correct answer so that other users who have the same question will know that it works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using OR means that if they are one user, they are *not* the other user. Everything needs to be AND:

```
TEXT(Currency__c) != 'GBP (£)' && $User.Id != '00512000006evSC' && $User.Id != '0051H000007i6ya')
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't like mixing &&/|| with AND()/OR() as I find it generally less readable, but I think something like this should satisfy your requirement as all conditions must be false in order to throw the error:

```
AND(
    TEXT(Currency__c) != 'GBP (£)',
    $User.Id != '00512000006evSC',
    $User.Id != '0051H000007i6ya'
)
```

Alternatively, this could be written as:

```
TEXT(Currency__c) != 'GBP (£)' 
&& $User.Id != '00512000006evSC' 
&& $User.Id != '0051H000007i6ya'
```